# How to read a text file into separate lists python

Tags: python, file-io

Say I have a text file formatted like this:

100 20 the birds are flying

and I wanted to read the int(s) into their own lists and the string into its own list...how would I go about this in python. I tried

```
data.append(map(int, line.split()))
```

that didn't work...any help?

Comment: `map(int, line.split())` applies `int` to the *entire* line.  What caused you to think this would separate numbers from words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, I'm reading the file line by line, and splitting them.  I first check to see if I can turn them into an integer, and if I fail, treat them as strings.

```
def separate(filename):
    all_integers = []
    all_strings = []
    with open(filename) as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            for item in line.split(' '):
                try:
                    # Try converting the item to an integer
                    value = int(item, 10)
                    all_integers.append(value)
                except ValueError:
                    # if it fails, it's a string.
                    all_strings.append(item)
    return all_integers, all_strings
```

Then, given the file ('mytext.txt')

```
100 20 the birds are flying
200 3 banana
hello 4
```

...doing the following on the command line returns...

```
>>> myints, mystrings = separate(r'myfile.txt')
>>> print myints
[100, 20, 200, 3, 4]
>>> print mystrings
['the', 'birds', 'are', 'flying', 'banana', 'hello']
```

Comment: +1.  This use of an exception is **perfect**.  Remove the "I'm not happy..." business.  This is good.

Comment: Yeah, I read somewhere that exceptions should only be used for exceptional behavior, which isn't really the case here.  I removed it.

Comment: "exceptions should only be used for exceptional behavior" Not terribly true in Python.  True in some languages, but not Python.

Answer (score 3):

If i understand your question correctly:

```
import re

def splitList(list):
    ints = []
    words = []
    for item in list:
        if re.match('^\d+$', item):
           ints.append(int(item))
        else:
           words.append(item)
    return ints, words

intList, wordList = splitList(line.split())
```

Will give you two lists: `[100, 20]` and `['the', 'birds', 'are', 'flying']`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution. Note it might not be as efficient as others for very large files, because it iterates over `word` two times for each `line`.

```python
words = line.split()
intList = [int(x) for x in words if x.isdigit()]
strList = [x for x in words if not x.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 0):

`pop` removes the element from the list and returns it:

```
words = line.split()
first = int(words.pop(0))
second = int(words.pop(0))
```

This is of course assuming your format is always `int int word word word ...`.

And then join the rest of the string:

```
words = ' '.join(words)
```

And in Python 3 you can even do this:

```
first, second, *words = line.split()
```

Which is pretty neat. Although you would still have to convert `first` and `second` to `int`'s.

Comment: your answer is ok. But what about a more generic solution.The case were we dont't know the occurrence of string and integer in file. Like for eg `hello 1 2 check` in this case your solution will not work

Comment: @RanRag, true. I edited in that assumption after reading other answers, the question isn't clear in that regard. If it is always in this format I think the Python 3 one-liner is the way to go though. Assuming he's using Python 3 of course.

Comment: Yeah, in that case the one-liner is the best solution.