# Read each word and rest of line in Python?

Tags: python, string, input

Say for example that I had the string `'20 30 i love you'`. How can I store 20 and 30 into their own variables and the rest of the string into a third variable?

Comment: This looks familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950195/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-separate-lists-python

Comment: Haha yes. I'm using this to practice on python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
line = '20 30 i love you'.split()
a = int(line[0])
b = int(line[1])
word_list = line[2:]
```

Make a string out of the word_list if you want it as a single string instead of a list of words.

```
text = ''.join(word_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a, b, rest = '20 30 i love you'.split(None, 2)
```